# Ebean manyToMany not saved in transaction

Tags: playframework-2.2, ebean

I'm using play-framework 2.2.1 with Ebean. I have a manyToMany relantionship between Student and SchoolClass.

Inside a transaction, when a schoolClass is created, added to Student and saved, the respective bridge table is not filled.

```
@Entity
public class Student extends Model {
    ...

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<SchoolClass> schoolClasses = new ArrayList<SchoolClass>();
}

@Entity
public class SchoolClass extends Model {
     ...

     @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "schoolClasses")
     public List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
}
```

Code:

```
try {
    Ebean.beginTransaction();

    ...
    Student student = new Student();
    student.schoolClasses.add(schoolClass);
    student.save();

    Ebean.commitTransaction();
} finally {
    Ebean.endTransaction();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If the transaction is removed the code works as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have once experienced a similar problem, could you try it like the following:

```
List<SchoolClass> classes = new ArrayList<SchoolClass>();
classes.add(schoolClass);
student.schoolClasses.addAll(classes);
```

Comment: That was my "solution" also. Could it be a bug?

Comment: Yes, I think it's a bug.

Comment: I had the same problem but this solution did not work for me. What worked was to save the relation the other way around, the equivalent of: `schoolClass.students.add(student)`. I have no idea why, but it is the only thing that made it work.